# How to create a generic from list of interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have 2 interfaces and `AllTypes` type:

```
interface A {
    // ...
}

interface B {
    // ...
}

type AllTypes = A | B;
```

How can I use a generic to make sure an argument to a function is object with interface `A` or `B`?

```
// pseudocode
function test<T oneof AllTypes>(argument: T): void {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`<T extends AllTypes>`